# has_and_belongs_to_many association loads incomplete results

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, associations, rails-activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two models

```
class Activity
  has_and_belongs_to_many :photos, -> { where "deleted = false"}
end

class Photo
  has_and_belongs_to_many :activities
end
```

Let us suppose I have only 1 activity, and it has 2 photos

When I try to load a list of activities and eager load their corresponding photos only 1 photo is returned per activity

```
activities = Activity.all.includes(:photos)

a.first.id # => 1
a.first.photos.size   # => 1
```

The corresponding SQL queries run are

```
SELECT `activities`.* FROM `activities`
SELECT `activities_photos`.*, `activities_photos`.`activity_id` AS t0_r0, `activities_photos`.`photo_id` AS t0_r1, `photos`.`id` AS t1_r0, `photos`.`primary_photo` AS t1_r1, `photos`.`created_at` AS t1_r2, `photos`.`updated_at` AS t1_r3, `photos`.`deleted` AS t1_r4, `photos`.`url` AS t1_r5, `photos`.`thumbnail_url` AS t1_r6 FROM `activities_photos` LEFT OUTER JOIN `photos` ON `photos`.`id` = `activities_photos`.`photo_id` WHERE (deleted = false) AND `activities_photos`.`activity_id` IN (1)
```

The second query returns 2 rows when I run it in MYSQL.

Wierd right?

This is where it gets wierder

I do not eager load 'photos' but load it individually for each activity

```
activities = Activity.all

a.first.id # => 1
a.first.photos.size # => 2
```

So this time I get all the required data.

The corresponding SQL queries run are

```
SELECT `activities`.* FROM `activities`
SELECT `photos`.* FROM `photos` INNER JOIN `activities_photos` ON `photos`.`id` = `activities_photos`.`photo_id` WHERE `activities_photos`.`activity_id` = ? AND (deleted = false)  [["activity_id", 1]]
```

How can I get all my photos through eager loading.

Am I doing something wrong or is it some weird bug?

Comment: Change `-> { where "deleted = false"}` to `-> { where(deleted: false)}` ; Use `activities = Activity.includes(:photos).all` ; let me know if it fixed your issue

Comment: Activity.includes(:photos).all gives same output. 

Another issue I am facing is that changing to { where(deleted: false)} results in ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid exception - "Unknown column 'photos.deleted' in 'where clause': SELECT `activities_photos`.* FROM `activities_photos` WHERE `photos`.`deleted` = 0 AND `activities_photos`.`activity_id` IN (1)"... its not performing the join on the actual photos table when I use hash in the where condition

Comment: "Unknown column 'photos.deleted': Find the table's name which holds the `deleted` column, then add it here: `-> { where(your_table_name: { deleted: false })}`

Comment: This has solved the problem with using a hash. But still getting only the first photo using eager loading.